# Looking for a clever simplification of $\sum_{j=2}^{T_L}(j-1-O_L)(2j-n-1)+\sum_{i=T^U}^{n-1}(O^U-n+i)(2i-n-1)$

Tags: combinatorics, summation

I have the expression (which I got by adding up all the distances between $n$ natural numbers bounded by $a_n$ and $a_1$): 
$$\sum_{j=2}^{T_L}(j-1-O_L)(2j-n-1)+\sum_{i=T^U}^{n-1}(O^U-n+i)(2i-n-1)$$
Where:
$$O_L=1+\frac {1-n+a_n-a_1}{2}-\frac {1-(-1)^n}{4}$$
$$O^U=O_L+\frac {1-(-1)^n}{2}$$
$$T_L= \frac n2-\frac {1-(-1)^n}{4}$$
$$T^U=T_L+1+\frac {1-(-1)^n}{2}$$
The expressions I got for the summations were the most awful polynomials I have looked at in my life, no matter how much effort I put into simplifying them. I think it would be easier (and definitely add to the brevity of my post) to describe what I have tried instead of actually showing it. 

So, to be brief:

1. I tried expanding out the terms to be added up, pulling out the terms in that expression that had no indices and just adding up the ones that had. To no avail.
2. Rearranging the summation so that both sigmas have the same lower bounds, then compacting the resulting exrpession. Still, no result.
3. Getting the expressions first, adding them and then substituting the abbreviations for their definitions.
4. Doing the converse of ($3$)
5. Redefining both expressions in terms of the same abbreviations and looking for common factors. Still nothing.

To be honest, I think I have tried many other things that I cannot recall right now over the past couple days. Maybe I am missing some simple trick, or maybe (God forbid) the resulting degree three polynomial is just as complicated as all my calculations indicate. 

Anyway, I would like to know which one of these options it is. Thanks in advance. 

Guacho.

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised if that doesn't really simplify into anything nice.

Comment: Maybe it can be somehow made to look like a Taylor series expansion?

Comment: It seems that you can easily caclulate the sum for even and odd $n$ separately.